# Make a relativeLayout and it's child im my case an imageview act like one button

Tags: android

Hi im trying to accomplish the following layout.

I have two RelativeLayout, each one contains a TextView and an ImageView.

the imageView show to the user the choice that he picked!!.These two picture explains more what i want to do:

[image: normal state of the ui]

This Picture show th normal state of the ui, no click events. When user click on the bottom layout th imageview in layout top will be set to invisible  and the the image view in layout bottom appear showing to the user that the second choice was picked by the user. I didn't find it difficult to deal with this issue (setting click listener on relative layout and handle the visibility of imageview).

the problem that im facing is how to make all the relative layout act like one button " when relative layout is clicked it turns to blue at the same time the imageview turns to white!!

In short i would say how can i synchronize the two selector!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the property of you child view android:duplicateParentState="true"

[duplicateParentState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState)

Answer (score 0):

when you make ImageView visible/invisible in onClick even of RelativeLayout, did you try changing bg color of your RelativeLayout to blue/white?