# Android: Developing a login screen like Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, layout

I' trying to  develop a screen on my android app like facebook login (App iPhone/Android)
[App Facebook Screenshot](http://www.google.com.br/imgres?um=1&hl=pt-BR&authuser=0&biw=1280&bih=633&tbm=isch&tbnid=_Y0fQpHOLzVdNM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.macpost.net/1597/facebook-ipad-app-launch-set-for-october-4-at-apples-iphone-5-event/&docid=2ft66Oo_RXYNWM&imgurl=http://www.macpost.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/facebook-ipad-app-login-screen.png&w=768&h=1024&ei=FkfCT-aKL4uo8ATu2LC4Cw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=119&vpy=116&dur=1461&hovh=259&hovw=194&tx=149&ty=159&sig=115270935923857306579&page=1&tbnh=132&tbnw=112&start=0&ndsp=19&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:68)

How can I draw this separator line between these two edittexts: e-mail and password?

Thanks!!

Comment: how about a background with transparent EditTexts on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make a such effect you have just to make your own 9-patch drawable. i have alreaady done such thing on my app see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424654/make-a-relativelayout-and-its-child-im-my-case-an-imageview-act-like-one-button)

Layout top drawable unpressed
[image: Layout top drawable unpressed]

Layout top drawable pressed

[image: Layout top drawable pressed]

Layout bottom drawable unpressed

[image: Layout bottom drawable unpressed]

Layout bottom drawable pressed

[image: Layout bottom drawable pressed]

The only thing that left is to build two selector one for the top edit text and another for the bottom edittext and set them as backround for your edittext:

selector_top_editText.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_top_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_top_normal"/>

</selector>
```

selector_bottom_editText.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_bottom_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_bottom_normal"/>

</selector>
```

For your login page  you can use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_top_selector" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" 
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bottom_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
            android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

check this and keep me in touch if you find problems

Cheers

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answear.
Look at the borders, why my edittext is like this? http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9554/screenshot20120527at144.png

Comment: that's because you haven't use 9-patch image you used normal png image that don't stretch

Comment: are you familiar with 9 patch? if not send me your email i will send them to you!!

Comment: Hey K_Anas, thanks for your help! I think I cant send you a email at StackOverflow :(

Comment: email sent let me know if it works  exactly what you want or not.

Comment: Could you please send the 9 patch images to me also

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to draw a line between Views, this will help

```
<View
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="2dip"
         android:background="#FF909090" />
```

In case your are looking to have custom EditText, these link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844681/android-custom-edittext-ui) and [here](http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget) may help you.

Comment: Hey there!
I added this View between the two Edittexts, but it's uggly!

It' a LinearLayout, added:
1)EditText
2)This View
3)EditText

ScreenShot: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/1781/screenshot20120527at125.png

Comment: This is how you can draw a horizontal line in Android, you can change it's color(android:background), thickness(android:layout_height) and width(android:layout_width) as you wish.

Comment: If you are looking at exactly how Facebook login looks like, then you need to have a custom EditText class.

Comment: Yeah, but, I can't make the line "stuck" at the EditTexts, always have a space between them.

Comment: I have edited the answer and given you both the options, now you need to work your way through.